# htaccess mod rewrite 2 words

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

    RewriteRule ^ראשי$ index.php?page=main [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^ניהול גלריות$ index.php?page=galleries [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^ניהול דפים$ index.php?page=pages [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^ניהול משתמשים$ index.php?page=users [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^הגדרות כלליות$ index.php?page=settings [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^דיווחים$ index.php?page=reports [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

It's making an 500 internal server error, if I only put the lines with one word like "דיווחים" it works but when I add those with two words like "ניהול דפים" not working.

How can you fix it? (maybe the problam is in the space between the 2 words?)

- The language isn't the problem even if I use English it's not working.
- My address is like /ניהול דפים

Comment: This isn't a PHP question, consider removing the php tag.

Comment: It might be a problem with the fact that Apache expects things in English?

Comment: "The language isn't the problem even if I use English it's not working."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are writing there essentially are regular expressions.  You might want to try using a regular expression meta character to indicate the presence of a space.

Why don't you try something like this -

```
RewriteRule ^ברזילאי\sדן$ index.php?page=galleries [L,QSA,NC]
```

[The `\s` indicates whitespace.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: ok it removes the 500 error but it just searches the url in google -_- because there is a space.. p.s +1 for writing my name in hebrew :)

Comment: But we removed the space with the meta character.  You don't actually write the `\s` in the URL. Only in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: ofcourse.. my url is now this: "localhost/CMS/דן ברזילאי" but when i write this in the browser url it searchs it on google like its two words for a search

Comment: ok so i gauss you can't do 2 words in url, so how can you escape the dash '-'  i want to do like: ניהול-גלריות

Comment: not working than :/ my code is this: `RewriteRule ^ניהול-דפים$ index.php?page=pages [L,QSA,NC]
`

Comment: what exactly is not working? Are you getting another 500 error?

Comment: Are you sure that your `index.php` is not throwing the error somewhere in your script?

Comment: Yea even the apache log shows this: `[Sat Jun 09 21:33:08 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/CMS/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: Well, if it is complaining about the flags, you can do away with `[NC]` as there are no case sensitive characters in Hebrew. And also with `[QSA]` as you are not passing any query through the rewrite.  Leave only the `[L]` flag that says not to continue if a match was made.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12343/discussion-between-dan-barzilay-and-lix)

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite supports logging, so you could could add this to get more details:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

Also check apache's error_log, as it usually writes *something* on a 500 error.